# Google Chrome on the Mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome on the Mac (the beta or alpha or whatever they call it) for a little bit and it's already my favorite browser.  Massively fast compared to other browsers on the mac.

One thing that does not work is the ability to middle click on bookmark folder and have all the bookmarks inside open in its own tab.  Is this something that simply hasn't been implemented yet or is there a way to turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware the middle click ability as well as the bookmark sync is not implemented yet. The Mac releases seems to be significantly slower then the Windows one's. I have to admit I also find Google Chrome on the Mac extremely fast, however never really had issues with Safari.